# Can I specify some dependencies not rebuild?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

From https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html

```
-a, --no-rebuild
Do not rebuild project dependencies.
```

I got to know how to disable rebuild all dependencies?
Can I specify some of them not all of them not to rebuild?

Comment: Why do you want to do so?

Comment: @Raptor To save some time when building a big project and I don't need some modules compile every time.

Comment: *relax, sit back and have a coffee / beer.*

Comment: @Raptor aha.maybe u r right

Comment: Could you post the dependencies section from build.gradle indicating the ones you'd like to exclude?